# @DynamicUpdate - fails to query only changed results

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, dynamic

I have the below setup - and i'm trying to get DynamicUpdates to work in Hibernate.  When I try to run the below update - it WORKED on one day... I commited my changes to my project (GIT) and went to progress code.  After a few changes - the code that worked quit working.  I reverted back (Trust me - there are no chances at this point) and now the code doesnt work.  Below are the environment, and variables/setup.  Why doesnt @DynamicUpdates do what its supposed to do?  According to Baeldung (and several other sites) - **"@DynamicUpdate is a class-level annotation that can be applied to a JPA entity. It ensures that Hibernate uses only the modified columns in the SQL statement that it generates for the update of an entity."**

```
**ERROR - Hibernate is doing a full table(All Columns) update.**
Hibernate: update employees set address=?, email=?, fname=?, lname=?, phone=? where empid=?

**EXPECTING SQL STATEMENT**<br>
Hibernate: update employees set email=? where empid=?


**ENVIRONMENT:**
Java 15, IntelliJ Community 2021, PostgreSQL.

**CONFIG/CODE:**
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name="employees")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private int empid;
    @Column(name = "fname")
    private String fname;
    @Column(name = "lname")
    private String lname;
    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;
    @Column(name = "address")
    private int address;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "orgunit")
    private int orgunit;
    .....
    public Employee merge(Employee inEmployee) {
        this.setAddress(inEmployee.getAddress());
        this.setEmail(inEmployee.getEmail());
        this.setFname(inEmployee.getFname());
        this.setLname(inEmployee.getLname());
        this.setOrgunit(inEmployee.getOrgunit());
        this.setPhone(inEmployee.getPhone());
        return this;
    }
}


@Service
@Transactional
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements IEmployeeService{
    @Override
    public void updateEmployee(Employee employee) {
            Employee tmp = this.empRepo.getOne(employee.getEmpid());
            tmp.merge(employee);
            empRepo.save(tmp);
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW - I can bypass the use of this Hibernate functionality by a simple MERGE operation created by a reflective iteration on the objects FIELDs.

I am more intrigued at why this doesnt work the way it should - and would love to implement this DYNAMIC approach to updating DBase entities.

https://medium.com/@joantolos/merging-two-objects-in-java-5bc43cd8ab74

Comment: Sounds like something is wrong with your build environment or something like that. I bet if you decompile the class that you deploy, you will see that the annotation is not there.